# Windows 8 Pro Font cache issue

Tags: windows-8, fonts, windows-8-fonts

For making some kind of font installer, after some install and uninstall, my windows 8 Font cache , damaged, so in Microsoft work or other application that uses windows fonts, when I select any 3rd party font, system generated below error:

[image]

all fonts that listed in applications like Word, is not listed in Fonts applet in control Panel, So is there any way to reset font cache in windows 8 pro?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the font cache is only used by WPF and Direct2D applications and not by GDI applications like Word.

The fontcache should be this file: `C:\Windows\ServiceProfiles\LocalService\AppData\Local\~FontCache-System.dat`. Delete the file and let Windows generate the file again.

Comment: After Deleting those files in safe mode, Nothing Happened...

Comment: run Process Monitor while satrting the apps to see more details: http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Defrag-Tools/Defrag-Tools-3-Process-Monitor ,http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Defrag-Tools/Defrag-Tools-4-Process-Monitor. Look at the result column to see which calls fail.

Comment: It's Seems that process Monitor is not Compatible with win8 Pro X64 because nothing happens after extract and run Procmon.exe

Comment: It works fine in Win8. Looks like you have some serious issues which maybe only solved by a reinstall.